# Get id of ancestor element from onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, event-delegation

**MY OWN ANSWER PROVIDED BELOW**

How do I get an ancestor ID tied to a specific element type? (Special Request: The solution in JavaScript, not in jQuery if possible).

Right now I'm only beginning the code, and I'm at:

```
document.onclick = clickHandler;

function clickHandler(e){
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

I'd like to know where to go from here to get the specific information I'm looking for

I have a series of several ARTICLE tags on my page with unique IDs (box_1, box_2, etc...) . The desire is to click anywhere on any of these articles, and figure out which article has been clicked. This is because I want to manipulate the specific article's styling and properties based on what's been clicked.

My logic is this:

record click. 
If click is in box_*n*
manipulate sizing/position of

```
<article id="box_*n*"></article>
```

Also, in case it helps, it is NOT entirely necessary for me to try and capture clicks at the document level, but I figured this information would be available no matter where I clicked.

**MY ANSWER:**
Basically this will tell you all parent elements of whatever you click on, and for me, I stop it on my articles and grab their ID's. Thank you all for your input!

```
function clickHandler(e){
  var boxName = e.target;
  isArticle(boxName);
}

function isArticle(boxName){
  if (boxName.tagName === "ARTICLE"){
    console.log(boxName.id);
  } else if(boxName.parentNode){
    boxName = boxName.parentNode;
    isArticle(boxName);
    console.log(boxName);
  }
}

document.onclick = clickHandler;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a single listener on the body element, then use the related Event object to find any ancestor article elements, e.g.

```
<body onclick="getArticle(event)" ...>
```

Then the function:

```
function getArticle(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var article;

  if (target) {
    article = upTo(target, 'article');
  }

  if (article) {
    // do stuff with article
  }
}

// Find first ancestor of el with tagName
// or null if not found
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd upvote, but I don't have enough street cred to upvote yet. I used some of your logic, but didn't want the specificity of the while loop, instead, I just used a recursive function. I provided my solution in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post but I happened to have the same problem lately and I found out the solutions here are way too complex than it should be...
There actually a REALLY SIMPLE SOLUTION to that problem nowadays and it's:
using the - `Element.closest()` function. [here is the documentation on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

So the simplest solution is just writing it like so:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    var parentArticeId = e.target.closest('article').id;
    console.log(parentArticeId );
}

 document.onclick = clickHandler;
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

on your click event:

mark every div with a css class (event if the cssclass does not contain any style) then find all these elements by **getElementsByClassName** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

for each element get the id and move on with your logic

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to capture the clicks on your articles only.

```
var articles = document.querySelectorAll("article");//select all article elements
for(var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++){//iterate set of articles
 articles[i].onclick = function(){//assign a click event to each article
  var currentArticle = this;//when clicked, you can work with the article element
  var currentId = this.id;//when clicked, you can access article properties like id
 };
}
```

Comment: Cool solution! I like the logic and may use this. I was wondering though, is it possible to get the ancestor ids and then pull out he ones that are for article tags?

Comment: Can you clarify that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, in that your solution might work very well, but I'm wondering if I'd be allowed to structure logic that allows me to 1) capture event anywhere, 2) bubble upwards, 3) capture element types along the way, 4) stop on this type of element, 5) give me id of that element

Comment: 1) it will only capture the click event which occurs anywhere inside of an article element 2) if an element inside of an article element is clicked, it will bubble to this click event handler 3) capturing element types is something that you would instead do with navigating the DOM through .parentNode or .children 4) the event hanlder would be on the article element 5) `this` will refer to the article element (and as a result `this.id` will give you the id of that element.

Answer (score 0):

look at my code, it may help you.

```
<article id="box_1" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 1 content</article>
<article id="box_2" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 2 content</article>
<article id="box_3" onclick="clicked(this)">Box 3 content</article>

<script>
function clicked(clickedBox) { //get the box clicked
   clickedBox.style.fontSize="24px"; //change the font size of the box clicked
}
</script>
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't liked. You need to explain how your answer addresses the OP (other than "read the code…").